# Retrofit2 request paths not working as expected

Tags: retrofit2

I have this Retrofit2 service definition:

```
@GET("/samples/{sampleId}")
Observable<Sample> getSampleById(@Path("sampleId") String sampleId);
```

and the base URL is `http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/sampledb/`. I doesn't work. I get 404

However, if I use as base URL this one: `http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/` and I define the service this way:

```
@GET("/sampledb/samples/{sampleId}")
```

it works properly. Why? I don't want to put `sampledb` prefix in every request definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Retrofit 2.0 comes with new URL resolving concept. Base URL and @Url have not just simply been combined together but have been resolved the same way as what **ahref in HTML** does instead

Take a look at the image
[image]

- **Base URL**: always ends with /
- **@Url**: DO NOT start with /

For more info [refer this blog](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/retrofit-2.0/en)

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove the "/" from your GET annotation: `@GET("samples/{sampleId}")`